# AngularJS track by expression for lists that can add and remove items

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is there a nice way to use the `track by` feature for `ng-repeat` with editable lists, i.e. lists where the user can remove and add items to?

Existing objects already have a unique ID assigned while a missing ID is my marker to create that item on form submission.

Using `track by $index` would work as long as the user only adds elements to the list.
Using `track by myId` would work as long as the user only deletes or changes items in the list.

The only way I can see to realize that behavior is assigning a temporary random ID to a property of every new item and have a scope method which returns either the real or the temporal ID, whatever exists. Seems not so elegant...

As I can imagine this is a rather common use case, are there more elegant ways to handle this?

Comment: Why not add a property to your model: IsNew, IsDeleted, IsModified?

Comment: @hoeni: In a similar situation, I used the approach of assinging temparary IDs (negative values) which get updated once the item is saved on the server-side and assigned a real (positive) ID.

Answer (score 0):

I often add a property `cid` (client-id) to my models. I assign the property when I fetch the models or create a new one so that every model has a `cid`. Then I can do something like:

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="for item in list track by item.cid">{{ item.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
item in items track by $id(item)
```